# View composer not send var to view

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying since yesterday to view Laravel composers working in 4.0.6, but both hit the head, I do not know what to think.

I followed the tutorial by Laravel Brazil: Controllers with cleaner View Composer (http://www.laravel.com.br/controllers-mais-limpos-com-view-composers/)

Can you help me?
Follow all codes below (or part thereof):

**composer.json**

```
"autoload": {
  "classmap": [
    "app/commands",
    "app/controllers",
    "app/models",
    "app/macros",
    "app/services",
    "app/libraries",
    "app/viewComposers",
    "app/database/migrations",
    "app/database/seeds",
    "app/tests/TestCase.php"
  ]
},
```

**app/composers.php**

```
<?php

View::composer('layouts.default', 'CategoryComposer');
```

**app/viewComposers/CategoryComposer.php**

```
<?php 
class CategoryComposer {

  /**
   * compose method
   * Busca as categorias para a sidebar do front-end
   *
   * @access public
   * @param Array $view
   * @return Category
   * @since 1.0
   * @version 1.0
   * @author Patrick Maciel
   */
  public static function compose($view)
  {
    $categories = Category::getActive(false);
    $view->with('categories', $categories);

  }
}
```

**app/controllers/ProductsController.php**

```
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function getIndex()
{

  $products = Product::getActive(false, false);

  return View::make('products.index')
    ->with('title', 'Produtos')
    ->with('products', $products);
}
```

**app/models/Product.php**

```
/**
 * getActive method
 * Obtém a lista de grupos ativos
 *
 * @access public
 * @return Array
 * @since 1.0
 * @version 1.0
 * @author Patrick Maciel
 */
public static function getActive($optional = true, $list = true)
{
  if ($optional AND $list) {

    return array('' => 'Selecione (opcional)') + static::active()->lists('name', 'id');

  } else if (!$optional AND $list) {

    return static::active()->lists('name', 'id');

  } else if (!$optional AND !$list) {

    return static::active()->get();

  }
}
```

**app/views/products/index.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
  <li class='categoria_produto'>
    <a href="{{ URL::to('/categoria/' . $category->id . '/' . Str::slug($category->name, '-')) }}" title="{{ $category->name }}">{{ $category->name }}</a>
  </li>
@endforeach
```

Erro
[image: Error generated when I try to access a variable sent by the view composer. - CategoryComposer]

Comment: [This may help.](http://heera.it/laravel-4-view-composer-master-layout)

Comment: What? I dont see anything in your comment

Comment: It's a link, the text itself.

Comment: I was saw this link yesterday. Sorry, doesn't help me :(

Comment: you should use namespaces.... it will save you from headaches later.

Answer (score 0):

Brayan Rastelli (brayanrastelli), solve the problem for me:

I change the **view composer first parameter (view)** for a partial (works with any view, except layouts - I don't know why).

```
View::composer('partials.category_navigation', 'CategoryComposer');
```

And them, I include the `composers.php` in `filters.php` (last lines):

```
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Extra files
| -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| View Composers, etc
|
*/
require_once app_path() . '/composers.php';
```

And, in my view, I `@include` that:

```
@include('partials.category_navigation')
```

Thanks guys.